# Gamma function Eulera

Tags: functional-analysis

I have gamma function Eulera. 
Can I write that $\Gamma (n+3)=\Gamma((n+1)+2)=\Gamma(n+1)+\Gamma(2)=n!+1$?

And I'm not sure whether $\Gamma(2)=1$?

Comment: The function $\Gamma$ is not linear; $\Gamma(a+b) \neq \Gamma(a) + \Gamma(b)$.

Comment: So, how I can solve $\frac{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(n+3)}{\Gamma((n+1)+(n+3))}$?

Comment: Please choose another tag. This is not "functional analysis".

Comment: @KasiaPisaniak, what you wrote in your comment is Beta function $B(n+1,n+3)$

Answer (score 1):

You began well by writing $\Gamma\big(n+3\big)=\Gamma\Big(\big(n+2\big)+1\Big).~$ Now apply $\Gamma\big(x+1\big)=x~\Gamma\big(x\big).~$ Then repeat the process.